# JPA PersistenceContext in a distributed environment

Tags: jpa, distributed, cpu-cache

Based on my understanding, transactions are not flushed immediately once they are completed. They sit in a cache in memory and only get written to the DB when the EntityManager determines that it is cost effective to do so. I believe the L1 cache is utilized in this case, but correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is, in a distributed environment, is the cache used by the Persistence Context distributed?

Answer (score 2):

L1 cache (session cache, persistence context) always works the same way, no matter wheteher your environment is distributed or not. Session cache belongs to a session, and you can have multiple sessions, either on the same machine or on different machines, so that it doesn't matter.

In distributed environment you need to care about the second level cache, if you use it.

If you run your application in a cluster, you need to use cluster-capable L2 cache implementation, if you JPA provider supports it (see, for example, [21.2. The Second Level Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache) from Hibernate documentation).

If you have other applications accessing the same database, you need to carefully configure caching strategies to avoid inconsistency in critical cases and tolerate possible inconsistency in other cases.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how the L1 cache works when running in a clustered environment. I'm not sure I understand how it would work the same way in both a distributed and non-distributed environment. E.g. When clustered, L2 cached data is replicated. This happens when you have a clustered setup on one machine or across multiple machines. With the L1 cache, is data replicated or not in a clustered environment?

Comment: @citress: Session cache belongs to a particular session that belongs to a particular machine, therefore session cache doesn't need to be replicated.

Comment: Don't mean to be a pain, I'm just trying to understand. Session cache belongs to a particular session, but that session may not always end up on the same machine, right? In a clustered environment where failover is available, if the JVM goes down, the session and therefore its cache will have to be available somewhere else, no?

Comment: @citress: Perhaps I used an ambiguous term here. By session I mean persistence context (Hibernate session), not HTTP session.

Comment: I was told the EM will flush the transactions in persistence context when a select query comes in. If this is true and persistence contexts are not distributed across Hibernate sessions, then it seems like we could fall into a scenario where a user is querying for data in one session but that data might still be sitting in cache waiting to be flushed in another session?